# Bootstrap checkbox and radio input with font-awesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can anyone give me a solution to this problem on IE8. I have this:
HTML:

```
 <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked /><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-check"></i> Three
    </label>
```

CSS:

```
[type=checkbox] { display: none; }
label { cursor: pointer; }
[class*=icon-].icon-fixed-width { text-align: left; }
```

jQuery:

```
$("[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $checkbox = $(this)
    $icon = $checkbox.siblings("[class*=icon-]")

    checked = $checkbox.is(":checked")

    $icon.toggleClass('icon-check', checked)
        .toggleClass('icon-check-empty', !checked)
});
```

All work fine on modern browsers but on IE8 wont work.
What is wrong here?
**[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/rulernature/7kDJm/34/)**

ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a semicolon after each Javascript line. I think the IE8 Javascript engine "crashes" when you do not end your Javascript statement with `;`

```
$("[type=checkbox]").change(function () {
    $checkbox = $(this);
    $icon = $checkbox.siblings("[class*=icon-]");
    checked = $checkbox.is(":checked");
    $icon.toggleClass('icon-check', checked).toggleClass('icon-check-empty', !checked);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/franchez/K6Wjd/1/)

Comment: @Mark Bell nope, is not working  :( What is strange, if I remove display:none; from css and in page are rendered 2 checkboxes(the default one and the other from icon-awesome) is working ...

Comment: Is my fiddle example not working on your IE8 ?
If you tried to change directly your javascript code, are you sure cache have correctly cleaned ? I already had troubles with javascript cache and IE8.

Comment: @RulerNature This is not my answer; all I did was edit it slightly to improve the formatting...

Comment: @franchez yes I'm sure :| I think IE8 has problems with that .change on hidden elements .

Comment: @RulerNature I did additional tests and indeed not working. Maybe it would be simpler to apply your custom icon directly on the checkbox, what do you think ?